# Python - Calling a definition inside a class within another file

Tags: python

I am currently working on the framework for a simple turn based game. I am trying to call a definition within a class Inside of a separate file from my current one. The Program I am importing the moveset file from is called Pymon_Movesets. I am importing it into the Pymon_Main file. The code for both looks a little like this...

(**Pymon_Moveset**)

```
class normaltype():

    def scratch():
        type = normal
        slot = 1
        # Base normal type move
        damage = 2 * level/2
```

**Pymon_Main**

```
From Pymon_Movesets import *

def Initialize():
    Scratch = Pymon_Movesets.normaltype.scratch()
    Bite = Pymon_Movesets.normaltype.bite()
```

**My Error**

```
 File "C:\Users\samsc\Desktop\Pymon\Pymon_main.py", line 2, in <module>
     from Pymon_Movesets import *   File "C:\Users\samsc\Desktop\Pymon\Pymon_Movesets.py", line 3, in <module>
     import Pymon_main   File "C:\Users\samsc\Desktop\Pymon\Pymon_main.py", line 110, in <module>
     gamefunction.Initialize()   File "C:\Users\samsc\Desktop\Pymon\Pymon_main.py", line 26, in Initialize
     Scratch = Pymon_Movesets.normaltype.scratch() AttributeError: module 'Pymon_Movesets' has no attribute 'normaltype' The program
 '[4908] python.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

I am Using Visual Studios Python Editor.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing all the contents of `Pymon_Moveset.py` into the current namespace, however, you still call the class using the filename. Also, you need to create an instance of the class before you call a method. Lastly, you need to include `self` in the method signature, so it is bound to the class:

In Pymon_Movesets:

```
class normaltype():

   def scratch(self):
      type = normal
      slot = 1
     # Base normal type move
      damage = 2 * level/2
```

In main file:

```
import Pymon_Movesets
def Initialize():
   Scratch = Pymon_Movesets.normaltype().scratch()
   Bite = Pymon_Movesets.normaltype().bite()
```

However, if you want to access the methods in the class using the name of the class and not an instance, use `staticmethod`:

In `Pymon_Moveset.py`:

```
class normaltype():
   @staticmethod
   def scratch():
      type = normal
      slot = 1
    # Base normal type move
      damage = 2 * level/2
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing `from Pymon_Movesets import *`, no need to use `Pymon_Movesets` to call its `normaltype` function if it is a module-level / file-level function.

```
from Pymon_Movesets import *

def Initialize():
    Scratch = normaltype.scratch()
    Bite = normaltype.bite()
```